# characteristic function problem 3

Tags: probability

Find $ (a,b) $, for which function
$$ \phi(t) = a\cos(t) + b\sin(t) +ab $$
is a characteristic fuction for random variable.

Comment: What have you tried? Describing your thoughts on the question will both increase your chances of getting an answer (as people are more inclined to help when some effort is shown) and of increasing the quality of this answer (as any answer is more likely to be tailored to your specific background and current knowledge).

Comment: $|\phi(t)|\le |\phi(0)|=1$, hence $b=0$, hence $a=1$.

Comment: Hint:   Express $\phi(t)$ in complex exponentials.  Does this look like the characteristic function of a discrete random variable?